# Lock a game folder, without denying steam access

Tags: steam

My friend owns GTA 5, And we both love to play online, but he loves to play with mods and is scared he might get himself-banned (again), So he asked me to lock the folder, but if I do, steam doesn't have access anymore either.

Does anyone have any bright ideas?

EDIT 1:

Is it maybe possible to revoke access to the folder for the account but add an exception for the steam program?

Comment: This cannot be done. GTA needs to be able to write to its own folder.

Comment: would there be a way to segregate the "mods" into their own folder and lock that particular folder? allowing the necessary files to run the game be present but securing the game from being "modded"? not sure how you have things set up but figured it may be worth mentioning.

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms, No the mods alter the game directly, it is officially speaking not an game function...

Comment: Possibly keep 2 copies of the GTA5 game folder (if you have enough space on your drive since GTA5 has quite a lot of assets)?  One modded and one un-modded, switch them by renaming them before launching the application.  You could even keep a dummy text file (e.g 'modded.txt' or 'unmodded.txt' in them to keep them straight.  Just be sure to not try to go online when the modded folder is in use.  If this would work, you could also write a batch file to inform you which folder is being used prior to launching the application and change it if necessary.  You could also link a shortcut to the .bat

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that he doesn't trust himself. So he will use the modded one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical solution to this problem, there is a personal solution though: self-control.

Any process that would prevent your friend from modifying his own game directory would necessary prevent Steam and the game from required access to that directory as well. Both these applications run inside his user context and therefore derive their accesses to the data they require primarily from his permissions. Limit his permissions and you limit the game's and Steam's permissions too.

Your friend is wise to seek advice, but your best advice to him is that perhaps fear of bans will be sufficient motivation not to do bannable things.